# Get a least occurred value in a Map

Tags: java

i have no idea how to get the value in a map that occurred the least.

problem :

> Write a method rarest that accepts a map whose keys are strings and whose values are integers as a parameter and returns the integer value that occurs the fewest times in the map. If there is a tie, return the smaller integer value. If the map is empty, throw an exception.
>
> For example, suppose the map contains mappings from students' names
>   (strings) to their ages (integers). Your method would return the least
>   frequently occurring age. Consider a map variable m containing the
>   following key/value pairs:
>
> {Alyssa=22, Char=25, Dan=25, Jeff=20, Kasey=20, Kim=20, Mogran=25,
>   Ryan=25, Stef=22} Three people are age 20 (Jeff, Kasey, and Kim), two
>   people are age 22 (Alyssa and Stef), and four people are age 25 (Char,
>   Dan, Mogran, and Ryan). So a call of rarest(m) returns 22 because only
>   two people are that age.
>
> If there is a tie (two or more rarest ages
>   that occur the same number of times), return the youngest age among
>   them. For example, if we added another pair of Kelly=22 to the map
>   above, there would now be a tie of three people of age 20 (Jeff,
>   Kasey, Kim) and three people of age 22 (Alyssa, Kelly, Stef). So a
>   call of rarest(m) would now return 20 because 20 is the smaller of the
>   rarest values.

now i believe that this code give me the smallest int count but how do i get that value?

```
public static int rarest (Map<String, Integer> map) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Integer i: map.values()) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    int min = 0, count = 0;
    for(Integer i: list) {
        count = Collections.frequency(list, i);
        if(count < min) {
            min = count;
        }
    }
    return min;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the value of `i` which corresponds to the lowest count `min`. This should look familiar:

```
public static int rarest (Map<String, Integer> map) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Integer i: map.values()) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, rarestValue = 0;
    for(Integer i: list) {
        int count = Collections.frequency(list, i);
        if(count < min || (count == min && i < rarestValue)) {
            min = count;
            rarestValue = i;
        }
    }
    return rarestValue;  
}
```

Comment: This also needs to handle a tie, in which case return the smaller integer.

Comment: I don't know why , but it always return 0. When it supposed to return 22.

Comment: That's because there's a small bug in the code. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Jason your edit shouldn't have been rejected by those folks, sorry.

Comment: @MattBall, really nice! thank you.  I dont know what Integer.MAX_VALUE is but i'll look at that later on.

Comment: No worries - at least the result is the same.

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE is the maximum value an integer can have. Simply put, an integer cannot store a value larger than that, so it is a good starting point if you need to do any comparisons.

Comment: So the problem was that i set min to 0 as someone answered below.  So Integer.MAX_VALUE is a correct option to find the min in a list? btw, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this,

```
public static int rarest (Map<String, Integer> map) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    Collections.sort(list); // you need to sort the list first
    int min = list.get(0); // this is your bug, min shouldn't start at 0
    int count = 0, rarest = 0;
    for(Integer i: list) {
        count = Collections.frequency(list, i);
        if(count < min) {
            min = count;
            rarest = i;
        }
    }
    return rarest;  
}
```

1. Your bug is that min shouldn't be initialized at 0 but at the first value of the list
2. If you don't sort the list first, in case of a tie, you won't necessarily get the youngest

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what was wrong in the code. Your code looks clean and easy to read.